# jasmine javascript basic function test is failing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, automated-tests

Hi i am trying to start a simple jasmine test(using typescript), which seem to not work. what im testing is to see if a function is called in the else section of an inner function if a variable is not empty.

my function:

```
let getAndSet = () => {
    if (main.getApiAcessToken() === "") {
        main.addIframe();
        main.getGraphToken();
    } else {
        getCountry();
    }
};
```

this is the test:

```
it("should call Function get country if token that was passed not empty", () => {
    let main2 = main;
    main2.getApiAcessToken = jasmine.createSpy("getApiAcessToken spy").and.returnValue("not empty");
    let getCountry2 = jasmine.createSpy("getCountry spy");
    getAndSet();
    expect(getCountry2).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I don't seem to understand what might be the issue, i trying change to a normal js function or a this. function inside the main none of them seem to work it seems i'm missing somthing very basic in jasmine.

Comment: I can see you do setup the test. but where do you call the getAndSet method in the test? (not saying that your setup is correct, btw)

Comment: thanks i just noticed that, and  fixed it and still the same issue. also update the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name for your spy is wrong. Your spy is called `getCountry2` whereas in the code the method is called `getCountry`:

```
getCountry = jasmine.createSpy("getCountry spy");
getAndSet();
expect(getCountry).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bBL9P/506/

Comment: ty that fixed the issue.